# UIVIew Resizes on UIScrollView Scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiscrollview

I am developing app in which my parent view is UIScrollView and child views are UIView and UIButton.

When i click on UIButton i am increasing the height of UIView programatically(this works fine)

But after when i scroll my scrollView my UIView resizes to its original height, i also tried changing height of UIView in scrollViewDidScroll method but it doesn't work :(

**Please help..**

Here is my code snippet:

```
- (IBAction)ButtonClicked:(id)sender {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.8f delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone animations: ^{
        MyView.frame = CGRectMake(8, 243, 304, 400);
    } completion:nil];
} 

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    MyView.frame = CGRectMake(8, 243, 304, 400);  
}
```

***Thanks in advance !!***

Comment: you are using AutoLayout?

Comment: @John yes, but it changes its height on button click and resizes to original on scrollview scroll..

Comment: when you use AutoLayout the Frame is no more work. you have to resize your UIView with only AutoLayout Constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should connect left(top, width or height) constraints as IBOutlets and should change them.

Because view is re-layouted with auto layout constraints when you scroll scrollview.

So

myViewLeftConstraint.constant = 8 
myViewTopConstraint.constant = 243 
myViewWidthConstraint.constant = 304 
myViewHeightConstraint.constant = 400

like this.